# Cannot move or resize Anaconda Navigator window

Tags: python, anaconda, resize, gnome

Are there any way out to have a maximize button on the Anaconda Navigator window? I have installed Anaconda in Ubuntu & created a custom launcher using this tutorial https://www.how2shout.com/linux/create-anaconda-navigator-desktop-shortcut-ubuntu-20-04-18-04/ . The launcher works fine but it does not allow the user to move or resize the Anaconda Navigator window. Please help.

similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=anaconda+maximize+ubuntu

System config below:

```
roy@LinMan-roy:~$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               roy@LinMan-roy 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           -------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Kernel: 5.4.0-72-generic 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Uptime: 57 mins 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Packages: 3356 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Shell: bash 4.4.20 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Resolution: 1366x768 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   DE: GNOME 3.28.4 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: GNOME Shell 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM Theme: Nordic 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Theme: Nordic [GTK2/3] 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Icons: Tela-circle-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Terminal: gnome-terminal 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     CPU: Intel i5-3450S (4) @ 3.500GHz 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Memory: 5733MiB / 15979MiB 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+- 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`                                   
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

[image: Image added]

Comment: Thanks @merv for the edits. :)

Comment: Did you try right-clicking at the top bar? There is an option to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try clicking on the window and pressing "Alt" + "F7", this will make your mouse pointer turn into a clenched fist, and then drag until window shows the part that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have a PC with Debian 11 linux on it. I use the KDE windowing system.
The anaconda navigator and spyder windows could not be resized in the normal KDE sway by pulling at the edges.

As above: Right click on the window title bar. Click on "More Actions".  Then click on Resize. This seems to enable the normal KDE way to resize windows.  The change seems to be permanent

Note: this works for any KDE window.